# how to traverse both success and fail results in ValidationNEL?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

```
def myMethod: ValidationNel[String, RealResult] = {
    parsedVal = parseIt()
    parsedVal match {
        case Success(s) => s.successNel[String]
        case Failure(e) => e.getMessage.failNel[RealResult]
    }
}
```

How do I now after calling `myMethod` handle both success and error results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like the following?

```
import scalaz.{Success => SuccessZ, Failure => FailureZ} //to avoid any potential conflicts with scala.util equivalents

myMethod match {
    case FailureZ(errors) =>
        //TODO handle your errors here

    case SuccessZ(results) =>
        //TODO handle your results here
}
```

An alternative as suggested by @TravisBrown, is to use `fold` on the `Validation` e.g.:

```
def fnFailure(errors: List[String]) = errors.mkString(", ")

def fnSuccess(results: RealResult) = results.toString

myMethod.fold(fnFailure, fnSuccess)
```

Obviously you could inline the `fnFailure` and `fnSuccess` functions in the `fold` if you prefer.

Comment: how do you then extract the values from `errors` or `results` for example to print the error message or the RealResult?

Comment: I think that `errors` is a List with your errors `String` in it which you have defined as your failures, whilst `results` is a `RealResult`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this simply isn't a very good answer. Maybe the OP can read your mind and know where `SuccessZ` and `FailureZ` came from (presumably you aliased them on import to avoid colliding with the ones in `scala.util`?) but future readers may not have this gift. Also the `fold` on `Validation` would be arguably be a more idiomatic solution than pattern matching on the constructors.

Comment: @TravisBrown I think you are mistaken somewhat, if you are typically working with Scalaz then you `import scalaz._` which gives you the ScalaZ `Success` and `Failure`. I had rather assumed that by using `SuccessZ` and `FailureZ` it would be obvious that I was aliasing those to avoid conflicts. However, just to be clear I have updated my example...

Comment: @TravisBrown would I be able to use `fold` before knowing whether its `success` / `failure`? (FYI at first I was bewildered indeed at `FailureZ` took me some time to understand its an alias (newbie on scalaz).

Comment: @Jas, yes, with `fold` you provide two functions that tell what to do with either side, and the appropriate one will be used to transform the `Validation`.